# Como criar um array com o valor um?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Olá

Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira e qual seria a mais correta de criar uma lista (ou um array) com os preenchida com o valor 1 dado o comprimento de uma outra lista. Exatamente o que o numpy.ones faz (ou o numpy.zeros com o zero), só que de uma maneira bem manual, sem utilizar nenhum pacote ou artifício.

Eu não tenho nenhum código porque isso foi uma dúvida que eu tive durante os meus estudos e não consegui achar algo parecido em outros lugares.

Obrigado !

Answer (score 7):

Consegues replicar o `numpy.ones`, por exemplo, usando:

```
n = 10 # tamanho do array
arr = [1] * n
#[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você está procurando preencher um [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) com um valor específico use o método [`fill()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html#numpy.ndarray.fill), esse método preenche a matriz com um valor escalar.

Exemplos obtidos na própria documentação:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2])
>>> a.fill(0)
>>> a
array([0, 0])
>>> a = np.empty(2)
>>> a.fill(1)
>>> a
array([1.,  1.])
```

Exemplo traduzido e obtido na [fonte dos métodos `ones()` e `zeros()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/578f4e7dca4701637284c782d8c74c0d5b688341/numpy/matlib.py#L13)

```
def ones(shape, dtype=None, order='C'):
    """
     Matriz de uns.
         Retorna uma matriz de determinada forma e tipo, preenchida com uns.
         Parâmetros
         ----------
         shape: {sequência de entradas, int}
             Forma da matriz
         dtype: tipo de dados, opcional
             O tipo de dados desejado para a matriz, o padrão é np.float64.
         order: {'C', 'F'}, opcional
             Se a matriz é armazenada em ordem C ou Fortran-contígua,
             o padrão é 'C'.
         Retorno
         -------
         retorno: matriz
             Matriz de formas, tipos e ordens determinados.
         Veja também
         --------
         ones: matriz de uns.
         matlib.zeros: matriz zero.
         Notas
         -----
         Se `shape` tiver o comprimento um, ou seja,` `(N,)` `ou for um escalar` `N``,
         `out 'se torna uma matriz de linha única de forma` `(1, N)` `.
         Exemplos
         --------
    >>> np.matlib.ones((2,3))
    matrix([[1.,  1.,  1.],
            [1.,  1.,  1.]])
    >>> np.matlib.ones(2)
    matrix([[1.,  1.]])
    """
    a = ndarray.__new__(matrix, shape, dtype, order=order)
    a.fill(1)
    return a

def zeros(shape, dtype=None, order='C'):
    """
     Matriz de zeros.
     Retorne uma matriz de determinada forma e tipo, preenchida com zeros.
         Parâmetros
         ----------
         shape: int ou sequência de ints
             Forma da matriz
         dtype: tipo de dados, opcional
             O tipo de dados desejado para a matriz, o padrão é float.
         order: {'C', 'F'}, opcional
             Se o resultado deve ser armazenado em ordem C ou Fortran-contígua,
             o padrão é 'C'.
         Devoluções
         -------
         saída: matriz
             Matriz zero de determinada forma, tipo e ordem.
         Veja também
         --------
         numpy.zeros: Função de matriz equivalente.
         matlib.ones: Retorna uma matriz de unidades.
         Notas
         -----
         Se `shape` tiver o comprimento um, ou seja,` `(N,)` `ou for um escalar` `N``,
         `out 'se torna uma matriz de linha única de forma` `(1, N)` `.
         Exemplos
         --------

    >>> import numpy.matlib
    >>> np.matlib.zeros((2, 3))
    matrix([[0.,  0.,  0.],
            [0.,  0.,  0.]])
    >>> np.matlib.zeros(2)
    matrix([[0.,  0.]])
    """
    a = ndarray.__new__(matrix, shape, dtype, order=order)
    a.fill(0)
    return a
```